# how to disable UITextTapRecognizer on a UITextView

Tags: uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to try to disable the UITextTapRecognizer, which I think is a built in property of the UITextView, as I suspect it is interfering with a tap gesture recognizer that I want to implement. How is it possible to do this?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this answers your question directly (i.e. "disable the UITextTapRecognizer"), but I think it might help. You can prevent that tapRecognizer from recognizing gestures, thereby basically "disabling" it (I think).

> "You can prevent gesture recognizers from looking at specific touches
>   or from even recognizing a gesture. You can specify these “prevention”
>   relationships using either  delegation methods or overriding methods
>   declared by the UIGestureRecognizer class.
>
> The UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol declares two optional methods
>   that prevent specific gesture recognizers from recognizing gestures on
>   a case-by-case basis."

Try the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` or `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` delegate protocol methods.

> "In addition, there are two UIGestureRecognizer methods (declared in
>   UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h) that effect the same behavior as these
>   delegation methods. A subclass can override these methods to define
>   class-wide prevention rules."

look at:

```
- (BOOL)canPreventGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventedGestureRecognizer;
- (BOOL)canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventingGestureRecognizer;
```

source: [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) (event handling guide for iOS)

I hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sure it will. I will try it.